# Wait for all Ajax request in each-loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make sure `anotherFunction()` is called only when all the Ajax request are done without using `async: false`?

```js
$(data).each(function(index, item) {
    
    $.ajax({
        url: "someUrl.com/someData?Id=" + item.id,
        success: function(result) {
            someFunction(result);
        }
    });

    anotherFunction();
        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you need to use promise.all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), which will only fire the `.then` when all promises it is passed have completed:

```
let requests = [];

$(data).each(function(index, item) {

  let request = $.ajax({
    url: "someUrl.com/someData?Id=" + item.id,
    success: function(result) {
      someFunction(result);
    }
  });

  requests.push(request);

});

Promise.all(requests).then(() => anotherFunction());
```

Comment: This would be more pragmatic as `let requests = $(data).map((index, item) => $.ajax(...));`

Comment: @AndyRay -- good point-- this can definitely be written to be more succinct.

Comment: This is a duplicate many many times over. Please refrain from answering them.